# Why doesn't concurrency speed up my fibonacci function?

Tags: go, concurrency, goroutine

Here is the following concurrency example from A Tour of Go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func fibonacci(n int, c chan int) {
    x, y := 0, 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        c <- x
        x, y = y, x+y
    }
    close(c)
}

func main() {
    c := make(chan int, 10)
    go fibonacci(cap(c), c)
    for i := range c {
        fmt.Println(i)
    }
}
```

I modified it to not use goroutines:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)



func fibonacci(n int) int{


    if(n==0||n==1){
        return 1
    }
    x:= 1
    y:= 1
    for i := 0; i < n; i++ {
        tmp := x
        x = y
        y = tmp + y
        fmt.Println(x)
    }
    return x
}


func main(){


    fibonacci2(100)

}
```

However, the time it takes are both nearly instant at n = 100000.
Does anyone have an example where goroutines does speed up calculations? I am wondering if perhaps there are some compiler settings that is limiting the number of cores my program can use.
Why doesn't the goroutines speed up the calculations?

Comment: First step is to make the code *not* 'nearly instant' - for a performance analysis there should be a 'not trivially irrelevant' baseline established D:

Comment: Concurrency != parallelism.

Comment: @user2864740 By increase n to 1 billion. The concurrent code is about 30-50% slower. 665ms vs 428ms. I ran it 10 times just to account for variance.

Answer (score 3):

These 2 versions take almost exactly the same time because most of the work is in the Fibonacci function, so it doesn't matter whether it runs on the main goroutine, or a separate goroutine. When `n` is large, the concurrent version can be slower, because of the communication overhead over channels.

[image]

You can see from the above diagram, the only work running on the main thread are 'Println' calls, which take very little time to run. 
But if the processing of the number on the main thread takes more time, using a goroutine to generate fibonacci number may be faster.